# Nvidia driver gets deleted after a few hours

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

This is really a weird bug, since about 2 weeks ago, my graphics driver gets deleted automatically (without any warning, and in the background without me knowing).

Here is what happens:

1. I update to the latest version of the graphics card (GTX 1070).
2. After several hours/a day (**without restart or shutdown**), when I try to open up a game or something that uses the GPU, I get an error that my GPU isn't supporting the OpenGL/DirectX Version...
3. I look at Nvidia Geforce Experince, and indeed, my graphic card needs to be updated...

And the same procedure repeat over and over, **on the same driver version**.

Another node that might be helpful, when I try to open up the Nvidia control panel, it opens up and freeze, than crash.

Any idea what is happening and how I can fix it?

Can the GPU be the cause?

And there isn't something specific I am doing to trigger that event, it just comes up randomly it seems.. I tried to scan for viruses (ESET + Malwarebytes) and both came up with nothing.

EDIT:
The version I am installing is 397.31, when I need to update and I get a glimpse of the Nividia Control Panel, I see the same version and then it crashes.

If I am missing any information let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all NVIDIA software, uninstall your graphic adapter.

Reboot computer.

Open Device Manager and find out the graphics card (GTX 1070), update driver software.

Search automatically for updated driver software.

Make system is up to date.

Comment: Tried to uninstall everything and rebooted several times, the system is up to date and there is no further updates than the 397.31 one I installed

Comment: Yes, 397.31 is the latest version on NVIDIA website, have you upgraded to 1803? My friend's GTX 1060 appears issue after upgrade to 1803. Don't install driver software by yourself, let Windows install driver automatcially

Comment: What do you mean by 1803?

Comment: I mean that if you installed 1803, NVIDIA 10 series graphic adapter may meet with trouble

Comment: Where can I see what version I have? I only see the version of the driver (397.31).

Comment: 1803 refers to the Windows 10 April 2018 Update. You can check in Windows Settings → System → About.

Comment: When uninstalling, try www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html to make sure that the system is clean.  This was designed to clean all the bits left behind by other uninstallers.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the BIOS and set your primary VGA to be PCI-E (not auto).

This fixed the problem for me.